# How can I diagnose a system freeze?

Tags: display

After installing Freya I noticed that my laptop hangs very often. I can however do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and back <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to get it working again. Could someone tell me how can I find out what is causing that and how to fix it?

Comment: You could try to run the `top` command in the terminal 1 (Alt+Ctrl+F1) and see wich process is consuming too many resources (if there is one)

Comment: @ikaro if switching TTYs is a solution, then it is likely not a problem with a runaway process. I had a similar issue with gala at one point which was later fixed by updates. This sounds more like a bug in the Window manager to me.

Comment: Most resource consuming processes are chrome, gala and Xorg.

Comment: Without further information, the question is too broad. For good reference, it's worth giving a look at the system logs https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles

Comment: did you got any solution? try open tty1 using.Ctrl+Alt+F1and run `sudo service lightdm restart`   please comment if solved